# What's wrong with my engines?

Tags: raft

I've been playing raft with my sister and dad. We just finished exploring Vasagatan and I'm trying to get engines so we can go to the next coordinates. I made two engines, assuming our raft wasn't above 200 foundations big. I tried to turn them on (both going the same direction and filled completely with fuel) but they stuttered. I shrugged it off and thought that it needed another, I wasn't super surprised. After making another and filling it with fuel, I turned them all on. Still stuttered... that sucks. I sighed and began to make a 4th one. I put it down and turned on the engines after filling it with fuel. STILL stuttered! I analyzed the wiki a few times over and everything was right. I know our raft isn't over 400 foundations big, there is NO WAY! After looking for a bit and checking if they were going the same direction multiple times, I decided I can't think of or find anything to do so I decided I should ask on a forum like this. Do my engines need to be further apart? Do they need to be on the edges of the boat instead of just having holes in the middle? Please help! EDIT: I did the math and turns out it actually IS over 400 foundations big! I got the last engine needed and now we are cruising towards the next destination! [image: My engines]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there wasn't actually a problem